# Cell-wise integration of a psd matrix is still psd

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, matrix-calculus

Let $A :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a matrix  valued function.   Suppose $A(x)$ is positive semi-define for all $x$.

Let 
\begin{align}
B= \int_0^a A(x) dx
\end{align}
where  $a>0$  and where the integration is done cell-wise.

My question is $B$ still a positive semi-define?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Note that by definition, $A$ is positive semidefinite if and only if $v^TAv \geq 0$ for every vector $v$.

We note that for any vector $v$, we have
$$
v^TBv = v^T\left( \int_0^a A(x)\,dx \right)v = 
\int_0^a \left[v^TA(x)v\right]\,dx \geq 0
$$
since the integral of any non-negative function is non-negative.